# How to find out what the player is looking at (by cursor)?

Tags: unreal-engine5

Unreal Engine 5
For example I have an actor (object like a box), I look at it and see his name at center of screen.
I've tried todo this, but didn't anything. Maybe I should use Vectors of camera (First Person View) or etc.?
P.S - Maybe some terms used not correctly.

Comment: You can use "Deproject Screen To World" to transform the mouse position of the player to a ray (essentially) and than use that information in "Line Trace Single" as input to do a raycast. The former should be easy enough, for the latter, Epic provides [a tutorial](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Tracing/HowTo/SingleLineTraceByChannel/).